# Change from button to on page load popup window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have problem to change this popup form. From button click to show this on load page. So when i open index page after 1 sec or 2 sec automatic show popup content.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>CodePen - Signup Newsletter Popup with Pure CSS</title>
    <style>
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins');

        .overlay {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
            transition: opacity 500ms;
            visibility: hidden;
            opacity: 0;
            z-index: 9999;
        }

        .overlay:target {
            visibility: visible;
            opacity: 1;
        }

        #popup1 {
            font-family: poppins;
        }

        #popup1 .popup {
            margin: 0px auto;
            padding: 50px 20px;
            background: #fff;
            border-radius: 0px;
            height: 260px;
            width: 690px;
            position: relative;
            text-align: center;
            top: 50% !important;
            position: fixed !important;
            -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
            -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
            -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
            -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
            transform: translateY(-50%);
            right: 0px;
            left: 0;
        }

        #popup1 .popup h2 {
            margin-top: 0;
            color: #333;
        }

        #popup1 .popup .close {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            right: 0px;
            transition: all 200ms;
            font-size: 30px;
            font-weight: normal;
            text-decoration: none;
            text-align: center;
            background: #333;
            border-radius: 0;
            cursor: pointer;
            float: right;
            padding: 0;
            color: #fff;
            margin-top: 0;
            margin-right: 0;
            height: 40px;
            width: 40px;
            line-height: 45px;
        }

        #popup1 .popup .close:hover {
            color: #06D85F;
        }

        #popup1 .popup .content {
            max-height: 30%;
            overflow: auto;
        }

        #popup1 .newletter-title h2 {
            font-size: 24px;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            color: #000;
            font-weight: 700;
            letter-spacing: 3px;
            margin: 0 0 15px;
        }

        #popup1 .box-content label {
            font-weight: 400;
            max-width: 560px;
            display: inline-block;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
            font-size: 14px;
            line-height: 26px;
        }

        .newletter-popup {
            background: #fff;
            top: 50% !important;
            position: fixed !important;
            padding: 0;
            text-align: center;
            -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
            -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
            -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
            -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
            transform: translateY(-50%);
        }

        #popup1 #frm_subscribe #subscribe_pemail {
            background: #EBEBEB none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
            border: medium none;
            height: 40px;
            width: 65%;
            margin: 20px 0;
            padding-left: 15px;
        }

        #popup1 #frm_subscribe a {
            cursor: pointer;
            border: none;
            background: #333;
            padding: 3px 25px;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-size: 14px;
            color: #fff;
            font-weight: 600;
            line-height: 34px;
            display: inline-block;
            border-radius: 0;
            letter-spacing: 2px;
        }

        #popup1 .box-content .subscribe-bottom {
            margin-top: 20px;
        }

        #popup1 .box-content .subscribe-bottom #newsletter_popup_dont_show_again {
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 0;
            vertical-align: middle;
            margin-top: -1px;
        }

        #popup1 .box-content .subscribe-bottom label {
            margin: 0;
            font-weight: 400;
            max-width: 650px;
            display: inline-block;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
            font-size: 12px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body translate="no">
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
        <title>POPUP Pure css</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins" rel="stylesheet">
        <div id="popup1" class="overlay">
            <div class="popup"> <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
                <div id="dialog" class="window">
                    <div class="box">
                        <div class="newletter-title">
                            <h2>Sign up &amp; get 10% off</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="box-content newleter-content">
                            <label>Subscribe to our newsletters now and stay up-to-date with new collections, the latest
                                lookbooks and exclusive offers.</label>
                            <div id="frm_subscribe">
                                <form name="subscribe" id="subscribe_popup">
                                    <div>
                                        <input type="text" value="" name="subscribe_pemail" id="subscribe_pemail">
                                        <input type="hidden" value="" name="subscribe_pname" id="subscribe_pname">
                                        <div id="notification"></div>
                                        <a class="button" onclick="email_subscribepopup()"><span>Submit</span> </a>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                                <div class="subscribe-bottom">
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="newsletter_popup_dont_show_again">
                                    <label for="newsletter_popup_dont_show_again">Don't show this popup again</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="btn btn-primary skip"
           href="#popup1"
           style="padding:6px 15px; background:#333; color:#fff; text-decoration:none; font-family:poppins; border-radius:3px; margin:25% 40%; display:inline-block;">
            OPEN POPUP
        </a>
</body>

</html>
</body>

</html>
```

This code works fine but with button Show popup content. I need to show same that content just on page load. And i think its some javascript code or jquery. If someone know how to do that, please write me.

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

As per your example, You have the id "popup1" and for this example, we can just add ready function and can add the href location to the id.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>CodePen - Signup Newsletter Popup with Pure CSS</title>
    <style>
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins');

        .overlay {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
            transition: opacity 500ms;
            visibility: hidden;
            opacity: 0;
            z-index: 9999;
        }

        .overlay:target {
            visibility: visible;
            opacity: 1;
        }

        #popup1 {
            font-family: poppins;
        }

        #popup1 .popup {
            margin: 0px auto;
            padding: 50px 20px;
            background: #fff;
            border-radius: 0px;
            height: 260px;
            width: 690px;
            position: relative;
            text-align: center;
            top: 50% !important;
            position: fixed !important;
            -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
            -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
            -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
            -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
            transform: translateY(-50%);
            right: 0px;
            left: 0;
        }

        #popup1 .popup h2 {
            margin-top: 0;
            color: #333;
        }

        #popup1 .popup .close {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            right: 0px;
            transition: all 200ms;
            font-size: 30px;
            font-weight: normal;
            text-decoration: none;
            text-align: center;
            background: #333;
            border-radius: 0;
            cursor: pointer;
            float: right;
            padding: 0;
            color: #fff;
            margin-top: 0;
            margin-right: 0;
            height: 40px;
            width: 40px;
            line-height: 45px;
        }

        #popup1 .popup .close:hover {
            color: #06D85F;
        }

        #popup1 .popup .content {
            max-height: 30%;
            overflow: auto;
        }

        #popup1 .newletter-title h2 {
            font-size: 24px;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            color: #000;
            font-weight: 700;
            letter-spacing: 3px;
            margin: 0 0 15px;
        }

        #popup1 .box-content label {
            font-weight: 400;
            max-width: 560px;
            display: inline-block;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
            font-size: 14px;
            line-height: 26px;
        }

        .newletter-popup {
            background: #fff;
            top: 50% !important;
            position: fixed !important;
            padding: 0;
            text-align: center;
            -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
            -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
            -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
            -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
            transform: translateY(-50%);
        }

        #popup1 #frm_subscribe #subscribe_pemail {
            background: #EBEBEB none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
            border: medium none;
            height: 40px;
            width: 65%;
            margin: 20px 0;
            padding-left: 15px;
        }

        #popup1 #frm_subscribe a {
            cursor: pointer;
            border: none;
            background: #333;
            padding: 3px 25px;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-size: 14px;
            color: #fff;
            font-weight: 600;
            line-height: 34px;
            display: inline-block;
            border-radius: 0;
            letter-spacing: 2px;
        }

        #popup1 .box-content .subscribe-bottom {
            margin-top: 20px;
        }

        #popup1 .box-content .subscribe-bottom #newsletter_popup_dont_show_again {
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 0;
            vertical-align: middle;
            margin-top: -1px;
        }

        #popup1 .box-content .subscribe-bottom label {
            margin: 0;
            font-weight: 400;
            max-width: 650px;
            display: inline-block;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
            font-size: 12px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body translate="no">
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
        <title>POPUP Pure css</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins" rel="stylesheet">
        <div id="popup1" class="overlay">
            <div class="popup"> <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
                <div id="dialog" class="window">
                    <div class="box">
                        <div class="newletter-title">
                            <h2>Sign up &amp; get 10% off</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="box-content newleter-content">
                            <label>Subscribe to our newsletters now and stay up-to-date with new collections, the latest
                                lookbooks and exclusive offers.</label>
                            <div id="frm_subscribe">
                                <form name="subscribe" id="subscribe_popup">
                                    <div>
                                        <input type="text" value="" name="subscribe_pemail" id="subscribe_pemail">
                                        <input type="hidden" value="" name="subscribe_pname" id="subscribe_pname">
                                        <div id="notification"></div>
                                        <a class="button" onclick="email_subscribepopup()"><span>Submit</span> </a>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                                <div class="subscribe-bottom">
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="newsletter_popup_dont_show_again">
                                    <label for="newsletter_popup_dont_show_again">Don't show this popup again</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="btn btn-primary skip"
           href="#popup1"
           id="foo"
           style="padding:6px 15px; background:#333; color:#fff; text-decoration:none; font-family:poppins; border-radius:3px; margin:25% 40%; display:inline-block;">
            OPEN POPUP
        </a>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script>
    $('document').ready(function(){
        window. location. href="#popup1";
    })

</script>
</html>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `setTimeout` method to get the output. run the snippet and wait for 5 secs to see the output. You can change the setTimeout value as per your wish

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>CodePen - Signup Newsletter Popup with Pure CSS</title>
    <style>
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins');

        .overlay {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
            transition: opacity 500ms;
            visibility: hidden;
            opacity: 0;
            z-index: 9999;
        }

        .overlay:target {
            visibility: visible;
            opacity: 1;
        }

        #popup1 {
            font-family: poppins;
        }

        #popup1 .popup {
            margin: 0px auto;
            padding: 50px 20px;
            background: #fff;
            border-radius: 0px;
            height: 260px;
            width: 690px;
            position: relative;
            text-align: center;
            top: 50% !important;
            position: fixed !important;
            -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
            -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
            -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
            -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
            transform: translateY(-50%);
            right: 0px;
            left: 0;
        }

        #popup1 .popup h2 {
            margin-top: 0;
            color: #333;
        }

        #popup1 .popup .close {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            right: 0px;
            transition: all 200ms;
            font-size: 30px;
            font-weight: normal;
            text-decoration: none;
            text-align: center;
            background: #333;
            border-radius: 0;
            cursor: pointer;
            float: right;
            padding: 0;
            color: #fff;
            margin-top: 0;
            margin-right: 0;
            height: 40px;
            width: 40px;
            line-height: 45px;
        }

        #popup1 .popup .close:hover {
            color: #06D85F;
        }

        #popup1 .popup .content {
            max-height: 30%;
            overflow: auto;
        }

        #popup1 .newletter-title h2 {
            font-size: 24px;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            color: #000;
            font-weight: 700;
            letter-spacing: 3px;
            margin: 0 0 15px;
        }

        #popup1 .box-content label {
            font-weight: 400;
            max-width: 560px;
            display: inline-block;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
            font-size: 14px;
            line-height: 26px;
        }

        .newletter-popup {
            background: #fff;
            top: 50% !important;
            position: fixed !important;
            padding: 0;
            text-align: center;
            -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
            -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
            -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
            -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
            transform: translateY(-50%);
        }

        #popup1 #frm_subscribe #subscribe_pemail {
            background: #EBEBEB none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
            border: medium none;
            height: 40px;
            width: 65%;
            margin: 20px 0;
            padding-left: 15px;
        }

        #popup1 #frm_subscribe a {
            cursor: pointer;
            border: none;
            background: #333;
            padding: 3px 25px;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-size: 14px;
            color: #fff;
            font-weight: 600;
            line-height: 34px;
            display: inline-block;
            border-radius: 0;
            letter-spacing: 2px;
        }

        #popup1 .box-content .subscribe-bottom {
            margin-top: 20px;
        }

        #popup1 .box-content .subscribe-bottom #newsletter_popup_dont_show_again {
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 0;
            vertical-align: middle;
            margin-top: -1px;
        }

        #popup1 .box-content .subscribe-bottom label {
            margin: 0;
            font-weight: 400;
            max-width: 650px;
            display: inline-block;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
            font-size: 12px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<head translate="no">
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
        <title>POPUP Pure css</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                //$("#popup1").hide();
                setTimeout(function () {
                    console.log("came");
                    window.location.href = "#popup1";
                }, 5000);
            });

            
        </script>
        <div id="popup1" class="overlay">
            <div class="popup"> <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
                <div id="dialog" class="window">
                    <div class="box">
                        <div class="newletter-title">
                            <h2>Sign up &amp; get 10% off</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="box-content newleter-content">
                            <label>Subscribe to our newsletters now and stay up-to-date with new collections, the latest
                                lookbooks and exclusive offers.</label>
                            <div id="frm_subscribe">
                                <form name="subscribe" id="subscribe_popup">
                                    <div>
                                        <input type="text" value="" name="subscribe_pemail" id="subscribe_pemail">
                                        <input type="hidden" value="" name="subscribe_pname" id="subscribe_pname">
                                        <div id="notification"></div>
                                        <a class="button" onclick="email_subscribepopup()"><span>Submit</span> </a>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                                <div class="subscribe-bottom">
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="newsletter_popup_dont_show_again">
                                    <label for="newsletter_popup_dont_show_again">Don't show this popup again</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <p><a href="#popup1"></a></p>
        

        
</head>

</html>


</html>
```